Drawing phase space diagrams from Hamilton's equations of motion
Consider a particle moving in the $(x,y)$-plane. Its motion can be described by the following Hamilton's equations of motion:
$$\dot x (t)=p_x+y$$
$$\dot p_x(t)=0$$
$$\dot y(t)=p_y$$
$$\dot p_y(t)=-y-p_x$$
I am asked to sketch two separate phase portraits for the system, one for each of the $(x,p_x)$ and $(y,p_y)$ planes. I am having trouble with the portrait in the $(x,p_x)$ plane. Since $\dot p_x(t)=0$, I expect there to be horizontal lines, however solving the system of equations shows that the particle has oscillatory motion in both $x$ and $y$ directions. How should the $(x,p_x)$ phase diagram look like?

Have you tried guessing a Hamiltonian $H$ that produces these equations of motion? Then drawing the phase portrait reduces to drawing lines with $H(x, p) = \text{const}$ (and does not require solving the equations of motion).

You have not explained your "However".  What is wrong with horizontal line segments? Two constants of the motion are trivial.

Answer self-evident?

You may rearrange your four equations into
$$\dot p_x =0\tag {1}$$
$$\dot p_y(t)+\dot x = 0\tag{2}$$
$$\dot x  =\dot p_y +2(p_x+y)\tag{3}$$
$$\dot y=p_y\tag {4}.$$
The first two reduce to two constants of the motion a and b,
$$p_x= a, \qquad p_y= b-x, \tag {5}$$
leading to the other two,
$$
\ddot x = -(x-b), \qquad  \ddot y = -(y+a).\tag {6}
$$
So, as you observed, $x-b$ and $y+a$ oscillate harmonically with unit angular frequency, as $B\sin (t +\tau_b)$ and $A\sin (t +\tau_a)$, amounting to linear segments of length 2B and 2A parallel to the abscissas on the two phase planes, centered at b and -a, respectively.
You may, of course, eliminate/fix some of the above constants at your convenience, e.g., A=B, and $\tau_b= \tau_a-\pi/2$.
The evident hamiltonian producing these equations of motion is $H=\bigl((p_x+y)^2+p_y^2\bigr )/2$, valued at $A^2/2$ for the above.
